# Unable to stop MySQL services which is schedule in cron

Tags: service

MySQL service are not able to stop which is schedule in cronjob.
I'm using below mentioned script.

```
intializeRestoration()
{
    /usr/sbin/service mysql stop
    rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql /var/run/mysql
}

**line 21: service: command not found**
```

Comment: ThIs question has nothing to do with mysql as the error is with the service part of the command.

Answer (score 0):

The user running the script does not have enough permissions